# Create smaller subnets from a large subnet which overlaps

Tags: networking, subnet

Historically our network is a 10.15.0.0/16. 
But now we must break this up into smaller subnets (company policy) for example 10.15.3.0/24 and when the transition is finished the /16 subnet will not be used anymore.
The problem is how do I go about splitting this up during the transition phase because I can't route from a  10.15.3.0/24 network to a 10.15.3.0/16 network. Maybe some kind of natting?

There are approx 50 HPE level 3 switches, routers/gateways etc. DC's with DHCP (for Workstations), DNS services, Exchange server,third party servers and we're getting a new VOIP System. We're connected to other locations across the country (Forest).
Does anyone have any ideas to put me in the right direction I'm in full control of the network so vlans routing etc should be no problem I just need a few ideas to get me going.

Appreciate any help

Tony

Comment: Can you use a different. IP block, for example 10.16.0.0/16?

Comment: How much do devices on (under the new plan) items speak to each other? Your problem is not routing from 10.15.3.0/24 to 10.15.3.0/16 - that should work OK. Depending on the hardware the reverse may not work. I would try adding a gateway IP for 10.15.3.? to my router and then changing the gateway of the clients.  You have less then 255 devices (or you need a bigger subnet) so you could even just renumber over a weekend.  If you run DHCP, your life could be even easier!

Comment: Hi Ron no I can't unfortunately

Comment: Davidgo thanks for the tip - most of the devices have got to talk to each other eg. DC Printers shares etc. Food for thought  I'll test that in my lab environment on Monday cheers

Answer (score 2):

This should work as long as your gateway for new smaller subnet has another IP address with "old" subnet as well. There are two scenarios. If computer on "old" subnet initiates connection to smaller network, it considers it locally connected, so it sends ARP request. ARP requests use MAC addresses and ignore subnet masks, so your device on smaller network still sees this request and replies "I'm here". Both ends create arp records and are able to communicate directly.

If connection is initiated by device on "new" subnet, it is little more complicated. IPs of "old" larger subnet are considered not local, so request is sent to gateway. Gateway should have "route" (i.e. network interface with old subnet mask) to larger subnet so it can pass request. After request is received by device on "old" subnet, it tries to send reply to IP which it considers to be local, so first scenario takes over, arp records are created and communication continues directly. However router is needed to establish communication.

This is somewhat grey area, so this configuration should be tested with your devices and router settings. I've tested it with linux network and everything works, but there could be problems with different software/hardware.

Comment: Hi Vitauts, I appreciate your reply to my problem - good ideas in there I'll give it a test next week - thanks

Answer (score 0):

To simplify what Vitauts explained, Netmasks affect if the sending host tries a broadcast ARP (on the local network) or contacts the gateway. Technically this is an ARP too, to locate the gateway (who has gatewayIP) if it isn't listed in the local table. As the name implies it determines the number of address bits which must be the same for a given segment.

Before you adjust a given host into a smaller network scope, a gateway needs to be defined in that scope and routing rules need to include the new smaller area. If you have a lot of hosts or complex relationships between them, this method of segmenting can run you into some weird problems depending on how different device network stacks take to the change.

The times I've needed to move a large flat network into a smaller segmented one, I found it easier to define a new network scope in a different private address block, e.g. from the 10.0.0.0/8 pool to 172.16.0.0/12. I've had people say it is more work, but it really is the same amount of work.

- It lets you document and map all of your changes and look for logical things that are going to break, (vpn links to client network conflicts were fun the last time) before you start moving things. [If you connect to clients over vpn and need access to local resources, you can't use an address scope that matches the one the VPN puts you into. The VPN link will have a faster metric and you wont be able to route to the local network.]
- Because you are in a new block, you can define and push out and test all of your new network routes well before you move any critical systems into them.
- The visual distinction pays big dividends long term if you need to do it to a live network without a lot of downtime. The computers don't care, but the completely different addresses use makes it very easy for us humans to recognize.
- The helpdesk can easily tell if the configuration difference is what is causing a problem or is it something else.
- You may also want to use the opportunity to define your new network segments around "power of 2" boundaries. This protects you from further problems if you need to expand or contract a segment in the future. Here I would define new /24 network segments such as `*.*.4.*`, `*.*.8.*`, `*.*.12.*`, `*.*.16.*`.

  In the future if I needed more devices in the `*.*.12.*` segment I can move that from a /24 to a /23 or even a /22 without it affecting any of my other defined networks. Because it is on the bottom address in the block of 4(power of 2), any expanded network space will be on address ranges deeper into the pool and not affect any other assignments I have in the current network.
- You will want to keep a full list of old and new IP's for the various servers. If an application is infrequently used, finding the server it thought it wanted to use in the new space is a lot easier, and you can then update the reference to one pointing at DNS so any future changes wont break break the software.